# What is the rationale of closing questions on SO?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

If a question is off-topic, unqualified etc. then users should be able to vote to delete it (so that noise is minimized), but I don't understand rationale for closing the question. Closing means no one can add any answers. what does it accomplish? if question is irrelevant then no one will respond. If someone wants to respond, then by definition the question deserves to be kept open and is qualified.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people would respond to any old rubbish.

Comment: "If someone wants to respond, then by definition the question deserves to be kept open and is qualified." <- No, there are enough people willing to answer off-topic or non-constructive questions.

Comment: Answering off-topic or unconstructive questions motivates such askers only to ask whatever they want which would flood SE with garbage.

Comment: And keep in mind that closure is not necessarily a permanent state. Sometimes a question is closed because it's not good enough in the current form. This gives the user an incentive to improve the question and have it reopened, while preventing users from answering a question which might dramatically change, wasting their time.

Comment: do old and abandoned closed questions end up getting deleted?

Comment: There are two primary states in which a question is considered "dealt with" on SO. One is "closed", which indicates that the question cannot be or does not need to be answered in its current state. The other is "answered" in which case the problem has been resolved. Both indicate to answerers that the question does not need further attention.

Answer (score 1):

When you close a question, the answers and comments are all preserved, so it can help future users. I have used many closed questions, whether as duplicates or otherwise, in programs that I have written. Deletions are for posts that just clog up stackoverflow with useless junk, and will not help anyone.